# table of contents - multi-line entries left-aligned

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting

[image]

I would like multi-line entries in the toc to have aligned line beginning. As in the example, "Nordbezirke" in the second line should start aligned with "Der Weg..."

Example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\special{papersize=155mm,232mm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[spelling=new,babelshorthands=true]{german}

\addto\captionsgerman{% Replace "english" with the language you use
    \renewcommand{\contentsname}%
    {Inhalt}%
}

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{pifont}
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{108}\ding{108}\ding{108}}

\usepackage[style=authortitle-dw,
edsuper=true,
namefont=smallcaps,
useprefix=true,
ibidemfont=smallcaps,
idemfont=smallcaps,
idembibformat=dash,
shorthandibid=true,
backref=false,
backrefstyle=none,
hyperref=true,
isbn=false,
backend=biber,
citereset=section,
edstringincitations=false,
bibencoding=utf8,
minxrefs=2,
mincrossrefs=0]{biblatex}

\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\MakeInnerQuote{|}

\usepackage{relsize,etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{displayquote}{\small}

\usepackage[papersize={15.5cm,23.2cm},left=20mm,top=20mm]{geometry}
\setlength{\headheight}{6mm}
\setlength{\headsep}{4mm}
\usepackage{setspace} 


\setlength{\parindent}{5mm}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
%[BoldFont = {Caecilia LT Std},
%ItalicFont = {Caecilia LT Std}]

\usepackage[chapter,nottoc]{tocbibind}      %index in table of contents
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% table of contents styling
\usepackage{titletoc}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\titlecontents{chapter}[0pt]{}% <above-code>
{\thecontentslabel.\quad}% <numbered-entry-format>
{\vspace*{-1.3em}}% <numberless-entry-format>
{\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\hspace*{0.5em}\thecontentspage}% <filler-page-format>

\titlecontents{section}[1.5em] % ie, 1.5em (chapter) + 2.3em
{}
{\thecontentslabel.\quad}
{\vspace*{-1.3em}}
{\titlerule*[0.75pc]{.}\hspace*{0.5em}\thecontentspage}[]

\titlecontents{subsection}[2.9em] % ie, 1.5em (chapter) + 2.3em
{}
{\thecontentslabel\quad}
{\vspace*{-1.3em}}
{\titlerule*[0.5pc]{.}\hspace*{0.5em}\thecontentspage}[]

\titlecontents{subsubsection}[5em] % ie, 1.5em (chapter) + 2.3em
{}
{\thecontentslabel\quad}
{\vspace*{-1.3em}}
{\titlerule*[0.5pc]{.}\hspace*{0.5em}\thecontentspage}[]

\titlecontents*{paragraph}[7.8em]
{\small}
{\thecontentslabel}
{}
{~(\thecontentspage)}[~---\ ]


%\titlecontents{section}[3.8em]{}{\contentslabel{2.3em}}{\hspace*{-2.3em}}{\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}
\newcommand{\mychapter}[2]{
    \setcounter{chapter}{#1}
    \setcounter{section}{0}
    \chapter*{#2}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#2}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace{13pt}}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% section chapter style global
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\p@section}{\thechapter.}
\makeatother
\renewcommand\thechapter{\Alph{chapter}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% styling of headings
\usepackage[raggedright,nobottomtitles]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\paragraph}[block]{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{0.5em}

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]{\normalfont\Large\filcenter}{\thechapter.}{0.5em}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{20pt}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\normalfont\large\filcenter}{\thesection.}{0.5em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\normalfont\normalsize}{\thesubsection}{0.5em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[block]{\normalfont\normalsize}{\thesubsubsection}{0.5em}{}
\titleformat{\paragraph}[block]{\normalfont\normalsize\itshape}{\theparagraph}{0.5em}{}


%\contentsmargin{0.5em}

\usepackage{url}
\setcounter{biburllcpenalty}{9000}
\setcounter{biburlucpenalty}{9000}
\setcounter{biburlnumpenalty}{9000}

% make title italic
%\renewbibmacro*{cite:title}{\ifsingletitle
%   {\setunit{}}% Löschen des \nametitledelim, falls kein Titel ausgegeben wird
%   {\ifboolexpr{
%           test {\ifentrytype{review}}
%           and
%           not test {\iffieldundef{xref}}
%       }
%       {\printtext[review]{\bbx@review{\thefield{xref}}}}
%       {\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
%               \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}%
%       \ifbool{cbx:addyear}
%       {\iffieldundef{year}
%           {}
%           {\titleyeardelim\parentext{\printfield{year}}}}{}}}


\usepackage[withpage]{acronym}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{xargs}                      % Use more than one optional parameter in a new commands
%\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}  % Coloured text etc.
%\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos,prependcaption,textsize=tiny]{todonotes}


\newenvironment{indentt}{\begin{list}{}%
        {\setlength{\leftmargin}{0.5cm}}%
        \item[]}{\end{list}}

\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks}
\urlstyle{same}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% new commands
\newcommand{\id}[1]{#1\,\index{#1}}

\newcommand{\z}[3]{\footcite[#3][#2]{#1}}
\newcommand{\q}[1]{\enquote{#1}}
\newcommand{\be}[1]{#1\index{begriffe}{#1}}
\newcommand{\beg}[2]{#1\index{begriffe}{#2}}
\newcommand{\ibe}[1]{\index{begriffe}{#1}}
\newcommand{\p}[1]{#1\index{personen}{#1}}
\newcommand{\pe}[2]{#1\index{personen}{#2}}
\newcommand{\bib}[1]{#1\index{bibelstellen}{#1}}
\newcommand{\ibib}[1]{\index{bibelstellen}{#1}}
\newcommand{\bibe}[2]{#1\index{bibelstellen}{#2}}
\newcommand{\pref}[1]{\cref{#1}}%\pageref{#1}
\newcommand{\paref}[1]{\cref{#1}}
%\newcommandx{\imp}[2][1=]{\todo[linecolor=red,backgroundcolor=red!25,bordercolor=red,#1]{#2}}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% deckblatt

\newcommand{\LMUTitle}[8]{
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \newgeometry{inner=1.5cm,outer=1.5cm,bottom=1cm,top=1cm}
    \vspace*{\stretch{1}}
    {\parindent0cm
        \rule{\linewidth}{.7ex}}
    \begin{center}
        \vspace*{\stretch{1}}
        \sffamily\bfseries\Huge
        #1\\
        \vspace*{\stretch{1}}
        \sffamily\bfseries\Large
        #2\\
        \vspace*{\stretch{1}}
        \sffamily\bfseries\Large
        #3
        \vspace*{\stretch{1}}
    \end{center}
    \rule{\linewidth}{.7ex}
    \vspace*{\stretch{5}}
%   \begin{center}
%       \includegraphics[width=2in]{siegelcenter}
%   \end{center}
    \vspace*{\stretch{1}}
%   \begin{center}\sffamily\LARGE{#6}\end{center}
    \newpage
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \cleardoublepage


%   \thispagestyle{empty}
%   \vspace*{\stretch{1}}
%   {\parindent0cm
%       \rule{\linewidth}{.7ex}}
%   \begin{center}
%       \vspace*{\stretch{1}}
%       \sffamily\bfseries\Huge
%       #1\\
%       \vspace*{\stretch{1}}
%       \sffamily\bfseries\Large
%       #2\\
%       \vspace*{\stretch{1}}
%       \sffamily\bfseries\large
%       #3\\
%       \vspace*{\stretch{1}}
%   \end{center}
%   \rule{\linewidth}{.7ex}
%   \vspace*{\stretch{3}}
%   \begin{center}
%       \Large Inaugural-Dissertation\\
%       \Large zur Erlangung des Doktorgrades der #5\\
%       \Large an der Ludwig--Maximilians--Universität München\\
%       \vspace*{\stretch{1}}
%       \Large vorgelegt von\\
%       \Large #3\\
%       \Large aus #4\\
%       \vspace*{\stretch{1}}
%       \large Erstgutachter:  #8 \\
%       \vspace*{\stretch{1}}
%       \Large Hamburg, den 25. September 2015
%   \end{center}
%   \newpage
%   \cleardoublepage
    \restoregeometry
}

\hyphenation{Mit-tel-stre-cken-ra-ke-ten Ver-ei-ni-gung Lu-xem-burg Lan-des-vor-sitz-en-der Meck-len-burg-Vor-pom-mern Weih-nach-ten Aus-ein-an-der-setz-ung Ver-ant-wort-ung Kom-mu-nis-ti-schen So-w-jet-uni-on hun-der-te Stell-ver-tre-ter Ge-stal-tungs-frei-räu-me in-ter-pre-tiert ver-öf-fent-lich-ten Meck-len-burg Sta-si-ver-ga-ng-en-heit}


\makeatletter
\def\@pnumwidth{2em}
\def\@tocrmarg {3.5em} % Also advisable
\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% header style

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[EC]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[OC]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[EL,OR]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot{}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{}
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\resetHeadWidth}{\fancy@setoffs}
\makeatother

\usepackage[bottom,hang]{footmisc}          % align footnote text for multiline footnotes
\setlength\footnotemargin{15pt}             
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{%
    \kern -3pt
    \hrule width 55pt height 0.5pt
    \kern 2pt
}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{#1}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}


\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \section{Die kirchliche Situation in der Meck\-len\-bur\-gi\-schen und Greifs\-wal\-der Landeskirche 1989/90}
    \subsection[Der Weg zur deutschen Einheit mit besonderem Blick auf die Nordbezirke der Deutschen Demokratischen Republik]{Der Weg zur deutschen Einheit mit besonderem Blick auf die Nordbezirke der Deutschen Demokratischen Republik}
    \section{Unveröffentlichte Quellen}
    \section{Veröffentlichte Quellen und Literatur}

\end{document}
```

Comment: First advise make a real MWE out of it and see / deduct if one of your commands / settings causes the problem.

Comment: It's the titletoc package, so my question really is why the line with \titlecontents{section} removes the usual formatting, and how to restore it.

Comment: Just make a small MWE showing the problem, there is a lot of stuff in your example that is not directly needed e.g. the package graphicx bibliography packages etc.