# Table of Contents : Consistent Indentation for Multi-Line Entries

Tags: table-of-contents

Much like what is asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/436679/161388), I would like all lines of a multi-line entry to be indented according to the header, like this :
[image]

However, the MWE below typesets as such :
[image: (image)]

How can I get the intended result, preferably without using another document class? Keeping the packages would be a nice option as well, but if `titletoc` doesn't support such typesetting, other packages are fine as well!

MWE :

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec,titletoc}

\renewcommand*\contentsname{Quick Answers}
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\bfseries}{
    \ifnum\thesection<10 Q 0\thesection
    \else Q \thesection \fi
}{0.5em}{}
\titlecontents{section}[0.5em]{}{
    \large \textbf{Q\contentsmargin{20pt}
        \ifnum\thecontentslabel<10 0\else\fi
        \thecontentslabel\enspace} }
    {\contentsmargin{20pt}\normalfont}{\titlerule*[1mm]{ $\cdot$}\contentspage}
    [\addvspace{-2pt}]

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Answer 1}
\section{Answer 2-a \\ Answer 2-b}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\contentslabel[<format>]{<space>}` for the contents label and add `<space>` to the indent in the first optional argument. Note, that you also have to avoid spurious spaces.

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec,titletoc}

\renewcommand*\contentsname{Quick Answers}
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\bfseries}{% <- comment the line end to avoid a spurious space
    \ifnum\thesection<10 Q 0\thesection
    \else Q \thesection \fi
  }{0.5em}{}
\titlecontents{section}
  [4.5em]% indent (.5em) + label width (4em)
  {\contentsmargin{20pt}}
  {% <- comment the line end to avoid a spurious space
    \contentslabel[\large\textbf{Q
        \ifnum\thecontentslabel<10 0\else\fi
        \thecontentslabel\enspace}]{4em}% <- comment the line end to avoid a spurious space
  }
  {\normalfont}{\titlerule*[1mm]{ $\cdot$}\contentspage}
  [\addvspace{2pt}]% <- changed 

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Answer 1}
\section{Answer 2-a \\ Answer 2-b}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I made it a bit differently than esdd, here is my solution:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec,titletoc}

\renewcommand*\contentsname{Quick Answers}
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\bfseries}{% <-- don't forget the percent sign!
   \ifnum\thesection<10 Q 0\thesection
   \else Q \thesection
   \fi
 }{0.5em}{}

\newlength{\contentslabelwidth}
\setlength{\contentslabelwidth}{3.5em}

\newcommand*{\myprintcontentslabel}{%
  \begingroup
  \normalfont\large\bfseries
  Q\ifnum\thecontentslabel<10 0\else\fi % always two figures
  \thecontentslabel
  \endgroup
}

\titlecontents{section}[\contentslabelwidth]{}{% <-- don't forget!
  \contentsmargin{20pt}%
  \llap{\makebox[\contentslabelwidth][l]{\myprintcontentslabel}}}%
  {\contentsmargin{20pt}\normalfont}%
  {\titlerule*[1mm]{ $\cdot$}\contentspage}
  [] % I removed the \addvspace{-2pt} here: it made the lines way too close to
     % each other.

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Answer 1}
\section{Answer 2-a\\ Answer 2-b}

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

You had several spurious spaces, beware of these (see comments in the code)!